# Keyword Search for .xlsx .ods files recovered by photorec

Tags: data-recovery, spreadsheet

Photorec recovered 3+ GB of files: buried in these files is a target spreadsheet that is saved in both the .ods and .xlsx format.   [Although Photorec recognizes spreadsheets](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec): it would be preferable to inspect each recovered file for a spreadsheet "fingerprint" in the guise of:

```
grep -rl "spreadsheet_fingerprint" ./
```

Is there a reliable "spreadsheet_fingerprint" for .ods or .xlsx files?

Answer (score 1):

photorec only recovers files that it recognises.

xlsx and ods are both zip archives, one of the recognised types, so photorec will have found the file.

For xlsx try grepping the start of all the zips for "xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"

```
for x in *.zip 
do 
 dd if="$x" count=1 2>/dev/null \
   | fgrep -b 'xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml' \
   && echo "$x is XLSX"
done
```

for ods

```
for x in *.zip 
do 
 dd if="$x" count=1 2>/dev/null \
   | fgrep -b 'mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet' \
   && echo "$x is ods"
done
```